# Javascript Promise Function Style

Tags: javascript, promise

Suppose I have a function that will return a promise that is based on some input value that need to be calculated first. It seems that there are two ways to do this.

**Example 1:**

```js
function foo(val) {
  var newVal = val + 100;
  var anotherVal = newVal % 12;
  var returnVal = anotherVal * 3;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(returnVal);
    }, 1000);      
  });
}

foo(10).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

**Example 2:**

```js
function foo(val) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var newVal = val + 100;
    var anotherVal = newVal % 12;
    var returnVal = anotherVal * 3;
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(returnVal);
    }, 1000);      
  });
}

foo(10).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

The first example keeps all of the setup outside of the promise function. And the second moves all of the logic inside of that function. On the surface these seem to be equivalent in pretty much every scenario. I was wondering if anyone had any insight into whether one of these is better than the other? Or if I am missing another method that is better than these two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between your two functions is where the variables are initialised, with the only difference being **[variable scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/variable-scope-javascript)**. Your two functions will both return the same result from the promise, but the **first** approach has the benefit of being able to access the variables within the function, while **outside** of the promise.

### Variables outside promise:

```js
function foo(val) {
  var newVal = val + 100;
  var anotherVal = newVal % 12;
  var returnVal = anotherVal * 3;

  console.log(returnVal); // Returns 6

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(returnVal);
    }, 1000);      
  });
}

foo(10).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

### Variables inside promise:

```js
function foo(val) {
  
  console.log(returnVal); // Variable doesn't exist
  
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var newVal = val + 100;
    var anotherVal = newVal % 12;
    var returnVal = anotherVal * 3;
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(returnVal);
    }, 1000);      
  });
}

foo(10).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

As such, it depends on **how** you want to use the variables. If you'd like to utilise them outside of the promise, opt for the **first** of the two functions. If you know you're never going to need access to those variables outside of the Promise, define them **within** the Promise to prevent **variable scope leaking**, in turn **[improving memory](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider another point here, if you have an exception inside the *Promise* and that promise's rejection is not handled properly then you would have an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error, where as in the first method you would just have a normal exception.

Comment: That's a good point. I was not thinking about how errors are handled.

Comment: I would upvote for the first paragraph and downvote for the second :-) No, the `Promise` constructor callback runs synchronously as well

Comment: @Bergi you are right, I've updated my answer. Thank you for pointing it out.